Getting issues while connecting Next.js to MySQL
I’m working on a Next.js project and I'm trying to connect MySQL using Drizzle ORM. I'm using boilerplate code from this GitHub repository as the starting point. I've followed the Drizzle ORM documentation for setting up MySQL, but I'm encountering issues during the connection process.
Here's what I've done so far:

Installed Drizzle ORM and MySQL dependencies:
`npm install drizzle-orm drizzle-orm-mysql mysql2 `


Created a drizzle.config.ts file with the following configuration:
   export default defineConfig({
    out: './migrations',
    schema: './src/models/Schema.ts',
    dialect: 'mysql', // Change this to 'mysql'
    dbCredentials: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST ?? 'localhost',
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT ?? '3307', 10),
      user: process.env.DB_USER ?? 'admin',
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD ?? 'psqrd',
      database: process.env.DB_NAME ?? 'name' },
    verbose: true,
    strict: true,
    });


I tried running npx drizzle-kit generate it gave output:
   Reading config file 'G:\next\user-authentication\drizzle.config.ts'
   Error
   at createConnection (G:\next\user-authentication\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:253:31)        
   at connectToMySQL (G:\next\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:71920:84)      
  at async Object.handler (G:\next\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:82977:39)
  at async rawCli (G:\next\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:81492:5)
  at async run (G:\next\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:81500:5) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined
  }

  G:\next\user-authentication>npx drizzle-kit generate
  No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
  Reading config file 'G:\next\user-authentication\drizzle.config.ts'
  Reading schema files:
  G:\next\user-authentication\src\models\Schema.ts

 1 tables
 guestbook 5 columns 0 indexes 0 fks

 No schema changes, nothing to migrate 


and while migrating:
 No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
 Reading config file 'G:\Bookme\user-authentication\drizzle.config.ts'
 Reading config file 'G:\Bookme\user-authentication\drizzle.config.ts'
 Error
  at createConnection (G:\Bookme\user-authentication\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:253:31)
  at connectToMySQL (G:\Bookme\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:71920:84)
  at async Object.handler (G:\Bookme\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:82977:39)
  at async rawCli (G:\Bookme\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:81492:5)
  at async run (G:\Bookme\user-authentication\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:81500:5) {
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: undefined,
 sqlState: undefined
 }



What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

"ECONNREFUSED" means that your MySQL isn't listening on the host or port you configured, or it was actively blocked by a firewall. Is process.env.DB_PORT configured, and what is its value? Why are you using port 3307 as the default (MySQL uses port 3306 by default)?
